# How do internal modules work in typescript

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

I am building a 3rd party package in typescript and I only want to expose one class to the end user of that package. I can't figure out how that is meant to work in typescript.

This is what I've tried so far

**moduleA.ts**

```
namespace internal {
    export class MyPrivateClass {}
}
```

**moduleB.ts**

```
namespace internal {
    import {MyPrivateClass} from './moduleA';
    export class PublicClassUsesPrivateClass {}
}
export = internal.PublicClassUsesPrivateClass;
```

This produces an error that there is no export `MyPrivateClass` in `moduleA`. I can get around this by exporting the `internal` namespace in `moduleA` but that isn't really private at that point.

If I don't import `MyPrivateClass` I get an error could not find name `MyPrivateClass`

Comment: In module, you don't need namespace.

Comment: If your MyProve class is really internal, you cannot use it in moduleB.ts.
There is no 'friend' module concept in TypeScript.